# ¿Cómo solucionar el error "0 Unknown Error, name : "HttpErrorResponse"" al mandar una peticion put de Angular al back con SpringBoot?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, rest, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde los campos **descripcion**, **inhabilM** e **inhabilC** son editables, y el update que realizo es a traves del campo fechaInhabil

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page">
  
        <div class="scrollme">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaInhabil">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> FECHA INHÁBIL </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fechaInhabil | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </td>
                </ng-container>


                <ng-container matColumnDef="descDiaInhabil">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <textarea matInput [value]="element.descDiaInhabil" [disabled]="!element.editable"
                                (keyup)="obtenerDescrip($event.target,element)"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="inhabilM">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> INHAB M </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-select [value]="element.inhabilM" [disabled]="!element.editable"
                                (selectionChange)="selectInhabilM($event.value,element)"
                                [disableOptionCentering]="true">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let inhabilMex of inhabMexder" [value]="inhabilMex.valor">
                                    {{inhabilMex.label}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="inhabilC">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> INHAB C </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-select (value)="element.inhabilC" [disabled]="!element.editable"
                                (selectionChange)="selectInhabilC($event.value,element)"
                                [disableOptionCentering]="true">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let inhabilChic of inhabChic" [value]="inhabilChic.valor">
                                    {{inhabilChic.label}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="botonEdit">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EDITAR </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="actualizar(element,inhabilModel)">
                            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="botonDelete">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ELIMINAR </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <button mat-icon-button color="warn">
                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons>
        </mat-paginator>
    </div>
</div>
```

en el metodo **actualizar()** recupero los datos de los campos editables, y utilizo la funcion  **formatDateToString()** para darle este formato a la fecha (dd/MM/yyyy) y asi mandar los parametros al service de Angular

```
actualizar(element: any, inhabilModel: DiaInhabil) {
    if (element.editable) {
      element.editable = false;
    
        inhabilModel.fechaInhabil = this.formatDateToString(this.idSelecc);
        inhabilModel.descripcion =  this.descripcionIngresada;
        inhabilModel.inhabilM = this.inhabilMSelecc;
        inhabilModel.inhabilC = this.inhabilCSelecc;
        this.diaInhaervice.actualizarDia(inhabilModel).subscribe(data => {
          inhabilModel = data;
         
         this.idSelecc = null
          this.descripcionIngresada = null;
          this.inhabilMexderSelecc = null;
          this.inhabilChicagoSelecc = null;
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Éxito',
            text: 'Registro actualizado correctamente'
          });
        });
      

    } else {
      element.editable = true;
    }

  }
  
  
  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Mi Service de Angular para realizar una peticion PUT, pero al ejecutarse manda el siguiente error en el navegador

```
export class DiaInhabService {

  constructor(private httpCli: HttpClient) { }


    private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8086/api/domain/public/v1.0.0/pymt/example/actualizarDia";
  
 

   

  actualizarDia(diaInhab: DiaInhabil){
    return this.httpCli.put<DiaInhabil>(this.baseUrl+"/"+diaInhab.fechaInhabil,diaInhab);
  }
```

ERROR

> ```
> core.js:4442 ERROR 
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url:
> ```
>
> 'http://localhost:8086/api/domain/public/v1.0.0/example/actualizarDia/20/07/2023',
> ok: false, …}
> error
> :
> ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
> headers
> :
> HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
> message
> :
> "Http failure response for http://localhost:8086/api/domain/public/v1.0.0/example/actualizarDia/20/07/2023:
> 0 Unknown Error"
> name
> :
> "HttpErrorResponse"

yo pienso que quiza sea por el formato de fecha al final del endpoint, que quiza lo este  tomando como si fueran 3 parametros, pero en realizad solo es un parametro de fecha el cual el formato es (20/07/2023) y no entra ni a mi servicio en SpringBoot

este es mi codigo de back

```
 @PutMapping("/actualizarDia/{fechaInhabil}")
    public void actualizarDiaInhab(@RequestBody DiaInhabilEntity entidad,
            @PathVariable("fechaInhabil") String fechaInhabil) throws Exception {
        try {
            diaInhabilService.actualizarDia(entidad, fechaInhabil);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            throw e;
        }

    }
    
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void actualizarDia(DiaInhabilEntity entidad, String fechaInhabil) throws Exception {
        try {
            diaInhabilRepository.actualizarCatDia(entidad.getDescripcion(), entidad.getInhabilM(),
                    entidad.getInhabilC(), fechaInhabil);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");

        }

    }
    
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE DIA_INHABIL I SET I.DESCRIPCION=?1, I.INHABIL_M=?2, I.INHABIL_C=?3 WHERE I.FECHA_INHABIL=?4", nativeQuery = true)
    void actualizarCatDia(String descripcion, String inhabilM, String inhabilC, String fechaInhabil);
```

al realizar una prueba unitaria si realiza el Update, y lo mando como el mismo formato

```
@Test
    void testUpdate() {
        DiaInhabilEntity exec = new DiaInhabilEntity();
        exec.setDescripcion("PRUEBA DATOS");
        exec.setInhabilM("0");
        exec.setInhabilC("0");
        
        exec.setFechaInhabil("20/07/2023");
        
        
        repository.actualizarCatDia(exec.getDescripcion(), exec.getInhabilM(), exec.getInhabilC(), exec.getFechaInhabil());
    }
```

pero al momento de hacerlo desde el Front, manda ese error, como puedo hacer para que en el Endpoint no lo tome como si fueran 3 paraetros, sino uno solo?

Answer (score 0):

La URL no mapea con ningún método del servidor. En este caso la URL problemática es `http://localhost:8086/api/domain/public/v1.0.0/example/actualizarDia/20/07/2023`. El caracter `/` tiene un significado especial en una URL y si necesitas enviar un texto con este caracter debes usar codificación URL (URL Encoding).
Por ejemplo, el caracter espacio en blanco se codifica en `%20` y el caracter `/` se codifica en `%2F`.

Puedes consultar esta [página externa](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) sobre URL Encoding.

Afortunadamente, el API de JavaScript tiene un método para codificar estos caracteres especiales de URL. Se trata de `encodeURIComponent()`. Ejemplo de uso:

```js
const url = "http://google.com?q=" + encodeURIComponent("Érase una vez");
console.log(url); // http://google.com?q=%C3%89rase%20una%20vez
```

Método actualizarDia() actualizado:

```js
actualizarDia(diaInhab: DiaInhabil){
    return this.httpCli.put<DiaInhabil>(this.baseUrl+"/"
    +encodeURIComponent(diaInhab.fechaInhabil),diaInhab);
  }
```